# An admin can edit own profile without having permission to access admins edit page

Tags: php

In my example, admins can have level 1, 2 or 3.

I have a users edit page, and this page can be only managed by admins with level 1.

And I was trying to give permission for users see own profile and edit own profile
 even when they haven´t permission to see the page (cases of level 2 and 3).

And while I was trying to do this, after many attempts, I "found" a method that is working.

But I'm not understanding how this can be working fine.

Do you understand how this can be working?

In my menu.php file, I have this "my profile" link, where each user can click to update his profile:

```
<a title="my profile" 
href="dashboard.php?exe=users/users-edit&userid=<?php echo $_SESSION['admin']['id']; ?>">
```

I also have a users index file where I have my list of users, and I have a link to edit each user:

```
echo '<a 
href="dashboard.php?exe=users/users-edit&userid='.$result['id'].'">Edit user</a>';
```

When I click in my link I go to my edit users page where I have this code ahead of everything:

```
<?php
if(function_exists('verifyLevel')){
    if(verifyLevel($_SESSION['admin']['id']) == '0'){   
        echo 'You dont have permissions to edit users.';
    }
    else{
        $userId = $_GET['userid'];
        $read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from admins WHERE id = ?");  
        $read->bindParam(1, $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $read->execute();
        $result = $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!$read->rowCount() >=1){
            header('Location: dashboard.php?exe=users/index');
    }
....
?>
```

And it is working like I want.

For example if admin have level 2 and he tries to acess my users index page he gets 'You dont have permissions to edit users.' message.

But if this admin with level 2 try to acess "my profile" link he have permissions to acess this page and edit his own profile.

But do you understand how this is workinf fine using == '0 in my condition??

This is my function to verifyLevel:

```
function verifyLevel($userId){      
    $pdo = start();
    $readUser = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM admins where id = :userId");  
    $readUser->bindValue(":userId", $userId);  
    $readUser->execute();
    $result = $readUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result['level'];    
}
```

Comment: You shouldnt do `if(function_exists('verifyLevel')){`. So, if something breaks in your code, access might unexpectedly be public. Just let the application crash if this important function is corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current mechanics look like they work out of luck, which certainly is not a good solution for security checks.

Just do the check exactly like your mind would do it. So, as a human, I would define the conditions like this:

```
Allow access if level is 1 OR if profile to be edited is his own.
```

Then try to do the code. Something like this...

```
if(verifyLevel($_SESSION['admin']['id']) == 1 || 
   $_SESSION['admin']['id'] == $_GET['userid']) {   
    // Do the editing stuff
} else {
    echo 'You dont have permissions to edit users.';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. I just dont get how my condition using == 0 its working fine.